# What does $ X \sim (\mu, \Sigma)$ mean?

Tags: statistics

From textbook: We write for a random vector $X$ with mean vector $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$,

$$X \sim (\mu, \Sigma).$$

Does that mean (no pun) that $X$ is almost equal to a function of $\mu$ and $\Sigma$? Or is it that $X$ is distributed like the product of the given vector and matrix?

Comment: You'll have to check your text, but things like that typically mean that $X$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$.

Comment: Thanks for answering, unfortunately I don't have the whole book, only selected parts/ chapters handed out from professor.

Comment: Have you checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution)?

Comment: @DerekElkins Usually $N(\mu,\Sigma)$ means normal distribution. The lack of a $N$ suggest for me an arbitrary distribution.

Comment: @leonbloy I agree, but rereading the question this is probably the book *defining* the notation.

Comment: @EricS. doing it now, just confused by the "missing" N :-/ thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean (no pun) that $X$ is almost equal to a function of $\mu$ and $\Sigma$?

No. The sign $\sim$ (or $\approx$) can mean "almost equal" that in other contexts, not here.

> Or is it that $X$ is distributed like the product of the given vector and matrix?

No. No product. It means what it has just said: the random variable $X$ has some probability density which is left unspecified, expect for these two parameters: its mean is  $\mu$ and its covariance is $\Sigma$.

Some comments suggest that a normal distribution is implied, but the standard notation for that is $X\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$. Which means that $X$ has a probability density function given by a gaussian density of mean $\mu$ and covariance is $\Sigma$. In our case, the density is not specified, only the mean and covariance.

Comment: thanks, I think I understand now. I am upvoting your answers, but my gratitude does not show yet :)

Comment: If all you know about a distribution is it's mean and covariance,  then any inference you draw based on it is equivalent to what you would have gotten had the distribution been a normal distribution.  Admittedly, you could say "X has this mean and covariance" and then later say "oh, and also this skew".

Comment: "any inference you draw based on it is equivalent to what you would have gotten had the distribution been a normal distribution" What a strange thing to say. Would that sentence still be true if we replaced "normal distribution" with other multivariate distribution?

Comment: This is going a bit afield of the question, but the normal distribution is the maximum entropy distribution given the constraint on the mean and covariance.  Given other constraints you would get other maximum entropy distributions with an analogous property.

Comment: The point is: "assume $X$ has mean/variance $(\mu,\Sigma)$ " and "assume $X$ is normal with mean/variance $(\mu,\Sigma)$ "  are different (not equivalent) assumptions. (That _sometimes_ these differente assumptions can lead to same conclusions in some inference scenarios is other thing)

Answer (score 1):

The book is most likely saying that the notation $X\sim(\mu,\Sigma)$ means that the random vector $X$ has a mean vector $\mu$ and a covariance matrix $\Sigma$.

Comment: Are you being sarcastic? Because you just repeated his top line. Either way, not really a helpful answer.

Comment: I'm not being sarcastic.  The text reads "We write for a random vector ..." I interpret this to mean "We use the following notation for a random vector ..."

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche, your answer seem so obvious that I'm a little ashamed for asking in the first place :-p

Comment: No need to be ashamed. :)